# Problem in parsing data from JSON object at client

Tags: python, json

I am making a client server program, in which the server is a Raspberry Pi connected with temperature sensors, flow-meter and heater. When the client sends a request for information, the server sends the json object, which should always be changing, as the temperature sensors values keep on changing.

But, I am always getting temperature and flow meter values as zero. If i am not putting try and catch, then i am getting the error => 
**raise jsondecodeerror("extra data", s, end)**
Please ignore the flowmeter reading. This reading is zero because my motor is off.
I have found that when two copies of json object are being received at client, then the error comes up.

{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.44"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.44"}

I need to keep one json object and neglect the other.I hope my question is clear enough. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Part of server code:

```
import json


def GET():                                                              

    # global heaterOn
    # global fanOn
    # global lowerThreshold
    # global upperThreshold
    # global flowRateThreshold
    global rateOfWaterFlow
    global temp1
    global temp2
    global heaterOn
    rateOfWaterFlowInString= str(rateOfWaterFlow)
    temp1InString=str(temp1)
    temp2InString=str(temp2)
    heaterOnInString=str(heaterOn)
    print("The value of TEMPERATURE 1 in string")
    print(temp1InString)

    a = {
    "RateOfWaterFlow":rateOfWaterFlowInString,
    "Sensor1Temp": temp1InString,
    "Sensor2Temp": temp2InString,
    "HeaterState": heaterOnInString
    } 
    b =json.dumps(a) 

    return b
```

Part of client code:

```
    #global data
    #command=input("Enter your command: ")
    # if command== 'EXIT':
    #     # Send EXIT request to other end
    #     s.send(str.encode(command))
    #     break

    # elif command == 'KILL':
    #     #send KILL command
    #     s.send(str.encode(command))
    #     break
    s.send(str.encode(command))

    reply= s.recv(1024)
    print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        data=json.loads(reply)
        print("\n The value stored in Data:\n")
        print(data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print("Error")



    print(data["RateOfWaterFlow"])   
    print(data["Sensor1Temp"]) 
    print(data["Sensor2Temp"]) 
    print(data["HeaterState"])
```

Results I am getting:

````
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0", "Sensor1Temp": "0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "0"}

 The value stored in Data:

{'RateOfWaterFlow': '0', 'Sensor1Temp': '0', 'HeaterState': 'OFF', 'Sensor2Temp': '0'}
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0", "Sensor1Temp": "0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "0"}

 The value stored in Data:

{'RateOfWaterFlow': '0', 'Sensor1Temp': '0', 'HeaterState': 'OFF', 'Sensor2Temp': '0'}
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "989.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.54"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "989.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.54"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.54"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.54"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.51"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.51"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.47"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF
{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.44"}{"RateOfWaterFlow": "0.0", "Sensor1Temp": "22.0", "HeaterState": "OFF", "Sensor2Temp": "21.44"}
Error
0
0
0
OFF```
````

Comment: Always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions, use version specific tags when appropriate and at your discretion.

Comment: Sir, please identify the error. I feel,i am unable to get the value of all variables except the "heaterState". New in python and doing json for first time.

Comment: have you tried just printing `data` to see what it contains.

Comment: I just try it now and update the question

Comment: I have re-evaluated the question. The problem is much much bigger than what i anticipated.

Comment: Problem is solved. Error in my Code